# Asynchronously waiting until a socket is available for reading/writing in Asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to do the following with Boost Asio. I have a socket and I want to register a callback to be called when data is available for reading/writing on the socket, but I don't want it to actually do the reading/writing. Basically, what I need is similar to `async_read_some`/`async_write_some`, except that the actual reading and writing is not done.

I need this because I'm using an external library with its own read and write function that require a socket descriptor as an input parameter and I want to use this library in an asynchronous way.

Comment: Do you want the code that using async_connect, async_write, async_read?

Comment: Only async_read and async_write. I can do the connect myself as the library uses sockets from already established connections, so I can use async_connect myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for reactor-style operations.  These can be obtained by providing [`boost::asio::null_buffers`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/null_buffers.html) to the asynchronous operations.  Reactor-style operations can be useful for integrating with third party libraries, using shared memory pools, etc.  The Boost.Asio [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html) provides some information and the following example code:

```
ip::tcp::socket socket(my_io_service);
...
socket.non_blocking(true);
...
socket.async_read_some(null_buffers(), read_handler);
...
void read_handler(boost::system::error_code ec)
{
  if (!ec)
  {
    std::vector<char> buf(socket.available());
    socket.read_some(buffer(buf));
  }
}
```

Boost.Asio also provides an official [nonblocking example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.nonblocking), illustrating how to integrate with libraries that want to perform the read and write operations directly on a socket.

Comment: `null_buffers` has been deprecated since Boost 1.66.0: [_"(Deprecated: Use the socket/descriptor wait() and async\_wait() member functions.)"_](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/null_buffers.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use `socket.async_wait(asio::ip::tcp::socket::wait_read, wait_handler);`